# Running Eclipse inside Tycho using reactor artifacts

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

Is there a way to make the `tycho-eclipserun-plugin:eclipse-run` goal resolve dependencies against artifacts in the current reactor <strike>or in the local repository</strike>. I'm trying to run the Eclipse/CDT headless build application as a step in our Tycho build, but I cannot figure out how to populate the Eclipse instance with the newly-built toolchain plugins.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>              
    <artifactId>tycho-eclipserun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <configuration>
        <appArgLine>-application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -import file:///...  -cleanBuild all</appArgLine>
                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/</url>
                        <layout>p2</layout>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <dependencies>
                    ...
                    <dependency> 
                        <artifactId>my.toolchain.feature</artifactId>
                        <type>eclipse-feature</type>
                    </dependency>
        </dependencies>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>eclipse-run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

This will fail since my toolchain plugins are not present in the Eclipse instance which hosts the headless build application. I could, of course, point out an external update site which hosts the plugins, but I would like to be able to use the plugins which are already being built in the same reactor. Is that possible?

EDIT: Original question included "or local repository artifacts", but that was not what I actually meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Earlier versions of Tycho allowed using artifacts from the reactor for the eclipserun-plugin, but this [caused problems for projects which build upstream artifacts from the artifacts they used for the eclipserun-plugin](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=393686), namely the Eclipse Platform. So to fix this, the artifacts used by the eclipserun-plugin were decoupled from the reactor & reactor dependencies in [Tycho 0.17.0](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes/0.17).

One could imagine ways to re-allow this use case, but this is currently just not implemented. AFAIK there are no concrete ideas yet how to do this. If you want to contribute one, you could [file an enhancement in Tycho's issue tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tycho).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could find is to use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the repository from the repository-module:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.iar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>my.toolchain.repository</artifactId>
                        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will copy and unpack the repository locally. It can then be specified as a repository when calling the `eclipserun` target:

```
<repository>
    <url>file://${project.build.directory}/dependency</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

The only thing you need to know is the GAV of the "eclipse-repository" module which contains the repository you need.

EDIT: This turned out to not work as I expected. It will pull artifacts from the local repository, and not from the reactor as I expected.

Comment: `${project.baseUri}/target` would be more portable than `file://${project.build.directory}`

Comment: Your solution is addressing the general problem of how to reference p2 repositories built by other reactors. Tycho could really have better support for that. We (as a larger organization) have a Nexus with the [Unzip Plugin](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Nexus_Unzip_Plugin) to solve this problem for us.

Comment: I think you may be able to skip maven-dependency-plugin altogether if you specify path to repository as `${project.baseUri}/target/repository`. This would also ensure that you won't by accident use a version of your plugin from a local or remote repository.

Comment: But `${project.baseUri}` refers to the *test* plugin, not the module building the repository. Or am I misunderstanding you? How can I refer to `${project.baseUri}` for another project in the same reactor?

Comment: `${project.baseUri}` is the location of the current project to which you can append strings like `/../siblingProject/target/repository`. Note however that this only works if you need that relative path in one project. If you put such a configuration in the parent POM, `${project.baseUri}` will be evaluated to different locations in every child project.